# How to add code to a function outside of its main body?

Tags: javascript

I want add code to a function, outside of the function and possibly even in an entirely different JS file. Is this possible? How can I do this? Here's a code snippet representing what I've tried so far:

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.firstName = ko.observable("Mike");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Rassel");

    // this was where I was originally making the call
    //myViewModel.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    //    return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName();
    })
}

// this is where the error is happening 
myViewModel.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName();

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

More code can be viewed at [this JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6E7Lq/).

Comment: Your code is not complete! You are missing `});`

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to add methods to already defined constructor functions in Javascript.

myViewModel.**prototype**.newFunctionName = function () {};

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/using-prototypes-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a function like this:
myViewModel.prototype.methodName = function(){}

This will serve as a good introduction to OO JS if you want to learn: http://beardedocto.tumblr.com/post/21920818233/oo-js-in-15mins-or-less